# How to make a object move step by step in threejs/tween.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween

I want to make my cylindre (pions in the code) move case by case to the object on a board that I create.
I have this code:

a : the start
index : the object

```
attachEvent(_this, index,a) {
if(index>=a){

_this.domEvents.addEventListener(_this.cases[index], 'click',        
function(event) {
for ( var i = a; i <= index; i++) {
  _this.stepByStep(_this,i)
}
}, false)
}else{

_this.domEvents.addEventListener(_this.cases[index], 'click',        
function(event) {
//nothing now
}, false)
}

}

stepByStep(_this,i)
{
_this.tween = new TWEEN.Tween(this.pions.position)
        .to({
        x:  _this.cases[i].position.x,
        y: _this.cases[i].position.y,
        z: 5},1000)
        .start();
}
```

When I run my code I don't know why but the pions goes directly to the object.

Comment: The code you've provided explains nothing. Could you create a live code example? (code snippets here, jsfiddle, codepen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Tween.js user ([TweenJS](https://createjs.com/tweenjs/) over here!), but I suspect its the same usage.

You are creating new tweens in your for loop each iteration, rather than appending new positions. It's basically creating a bunch of separate tweens that start at the same time and run concurrently, but all affect the same object. Chances are good the last tween is the one getting applied.

**EDIT** 
Apparently this is [how Tween.js works](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/blob/master/docs/user_guide.md)? Only a single to() call can be used for a tween. My original solution works for [TweenJS](https://github.com/CreateJS/TweenJS), but not Tween.js, which your example uses:

**ORIGINAL SOLUTION ONLY WORKS FOR CREATEJS/TWEENJS:**

Create the Tween one time, and append the `to()` calls in the loop:

```
var tween = new createjs.Tween(this.pions.position);
for ( var i = a; i <= index; i++) {
  _this.stepByStep(tween, _this.cases[i].position); // Arguments changed!
}

function stepByStep(tween, position)
{
    tween.to({
        x: position.x,
        y: position.y,
        z: 5
    }, 1000);
}
```

This makes a single tween, and adds `to()` calls for each position. I simplified the arguments a little as well to make the function a little cleaner (passing the whole scope is a bit messy). You can clean it up however you want.

---

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

Using Tween.js, it seems necessary to create a new tween for each new animation, but instead of creating them all at once, you must `chain` them, and only start the first tween.

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
var firstTween = new Tween.Tween(obj)
var earlierTween = firstTween;
(loop) {
  var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(obj);
  tween.to({params});
  earlierTween.chain(tween);
  earlierTween = tween;
}
firstTween.start();
```

Here is a quick fiddle I threw together. The drawing layer uses EaselJS, but the tweening is using Tween.js.
https://jsfiddle.net/0mh6kj5y/8/

I also noted that you referred to `this.pions` in your function, whereas everything else uses `_this` for scope.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thnaks for your help but I have the same result, the pions go directly to the last i cases (cases[index]) and it's not what Iam looking for.

Comment: Updated my answer, and created a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/0mh6kj5y/8/

Comment: Thank you but it's didn't work , I follow your pseudo code but when I click nothing happen and no error in the console